# Vuetify expansion panel body has display none style in testing environment

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Hello I'm currently having trouble in debugging an issue on my testing site, what happened is that the expansion panels are not showing because of some style attribute is attached to the div element of **v-expansion-panel__body**. This doesn't happen on my local. Both executes **npm run build** in building the app.

[image]

Below are my codes

**Template**

```
<v-expansion-panel
                    light
                    class="elevation-0">
                    <v-expansion-panel-content
                        v-for="(acl, moduleIndex) in aclModuleAndActionItems"
                        :key="moduleIndex">
                        <template v-slot:header>
                            <div>
                                <h3>
                                    {{acl.module_name}}
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                        </template>
                        <v-card
                            flat 
                            class="elevation-0">
                            <v-card-text class="pa-0">
                                <div 
                                    v-for="(action, actionIndex) in acl.action_names" 
                                    :key="actionIndex">
                                    <div class="pl-5">
                                        <v-checkbox
                                            :disabled="!role"
                                            :label="action | underscoretospace"
                                            color="green"
                                            class="pt-2 pb-2 pl-5 pr-4"
                                            @change="validateAclRole($event, role, acl.module_name, action)">
                                        </v-checkbox>
                                    </div>
                                    <v-divider v-if="actionIndex < (acl.action_names.length - 1)"></v-divider>
                                </div>
                            </v-card-text>
                        </v-card>
                    </v-expansion-panel-content>
                </v-expansion-panel>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
import { AclModuleAndActionItems } from '~/static/AclModuleAndActionItems.js'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            aclModuleAndActionItems: ( AclModuleAndActionItems ) ? AclModuleAndActionItems : [],
            role: ''
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**ACL Array**

```
export const AclModuleAndActionItems =  [
    {
        "module_name": "acl",
        "action_names": [
            "create",
            "destroy",
            "edit",
            "index",
            "show",
            "store",
            "update"
        ]
    },
    {
        "module_name": "projects",
        "action_names": [
            "create",
            "destroy",
            "edit",
            "index",
            "show",
            "store",
            "update"
        ]
    },
    {
        "module_name": "tasks",
        "action_names": [
            "create",
            "destroy",
            "edit",
            "index",
            "pending_task",
            "show",
            "store",
            "update"
        ]
    }
]
```

Display on my local

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using the below code for  panel headers and the style attribute is not added anymore to expansion panel header.

```
<div slot="header">
    <h3>{{acl.module_name}}</h3>
</div>
```

Not sure why using template is adding the style attribute in my case

```
<template v-slot:header>
    <div>
        <h3>{{acl.module_name}}</h3>
    </div>
</template>
```